# Overlapping hline into ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlapping, geom-text

I have made the following plot, the thing is that I want the hline to be above the geombars. Moreover I would like to know if I could display some text near the hline. For the moment this is the result:

```
sent%>%
  ggplot(aes(sent$screen_name,(as.numeric(sent$ave_sentiment)))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = (sum(sent$ave_sentiment)/15), color='black',size=1.25)+
  geom_col(fill = 'darkred') + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(label = (sent$ave_sentiment), y =(sent$ave_sentiment)+12), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust =0.5,size=3)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = sent$screen_name) + ylim(0,100)+ coord_flip()+
  ggplot2::labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL, #Info en cada eje 
    title = "Índice de negatividad por medio " #Texto 
  )

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3JW.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `geom_hline` call to be after the `geom_col` and it will show in front of the bars.

Comment: And when you say text near the hline, can you give more specifics?

Comment: Many thanks for the first answer, i am trying to display a text in the left hand of the hline, maybe it could be a geom_text or a geom_label in which I could display the mean of the values.

Comment: The mean value for each column? Or a single value for the line? The text in your image already looks good for each column. If you want that improved, please clarify what you'd like changed.